# API Platform - can't generate Entity from schema with no owned properties

Tags: php, symfony, schema.org, api-platform.com

I'm running the API Platform schema type-generator, but struggling with a type that is defined in schema.org, but has no properties of its own (http://schema.org/Duration).

When I run vendor/bin/schema generate-types, I get

```
[error] The property "potentialAction" (type "Duration") has an unknown type. Add its type to the config file.

[warning] The property "identifier" (type "Duration") has several types. Using the first one ("URL") or possible options("URL", "Text").
```

My types config is:

```
  types:
    Thing:
        properties:
            name: ~
    Duration: ~
    Recipe:
        properties:
            cookTime: ~
            recipeCuisine: ~
```

If I define one of the properties Duration inherits from a parent (Eg Thing->Name) it generates OK, but I'm not sure how to then set a duration property (presumably text) on it.
Perhaps I've mixed up how to use/define types that have no properties of their own - is there a way of telling the schema 'This is just a single text value'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not familiar with API Platform, but I think your question can be answered from the perspective of authoring Schema.org structured data:

#### Providing a text value (*recommended*)

You would typically not specify [`Duration`](http://schema.org/Duration) as type. Just provide a text value.

From Schema.org’s example of the [`cookTime`](http://schema.org/cookTime) property (which expects a `Duration` value):

```json
"cookTime": "PT1H",
```

```html
Cook time: <meta itemprop="cookTime" content="PT1H">1 hour
```

```html
Cook time: <meta property="cookTime" content="PT1H">1 hour
```

So its use is similar to [data types](http://schema.org/DataType).

#### Providing an item value

If you *do* have to provide it as type (for whatever reason), you could provide it as value for the `name` property, as there is no other suitable property defined:

```json
"cookTime": {
  "@type": "Duration",
  "name": "PT1H"
},
```

```html
<div itemprop="cookTime" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Duration">
  Cook time: <meta itemprop="name" content="PT1H">1 hour
</div>
```

```html
<div property="cookTime" typeof="Duration">
  Cook time: <meta property="name" content="PT1H">1 hour
</div>
```

But that’s not commonly done, and consumers might not handle it correctly. For example, Google’s SDTT reports a warning that it doesn’t understand the value "PT1H" as ISO 8601 date/time, while it reports no warning when specifying it as text value.